# How to make chrome without `--headless` behave the same as with `--headless` regarding session data?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I'm driving `chromium-browser --headless` through [Chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home) and [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Without `--headless`, Chrome does create a temporary profile. However, much more session data seems to be persisted between requests than with `--headless`. This means that, without `--headless`, my tests will fail unless I reinitialize Chromedriver between each test case. I would like to know which options I can pass to make the headful version of Chrome behave more like the headless version.

Chromedriver 2.32 and Chromium 61.0.3163.10